# Laravel. Use the table name in the where

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, controller

I have a controller in which there is a string

```
$models = Model::with('table1', 'table2', 'table3', 'table4', 'table5')
->where('name', 'hello')->get();
```

The problem is that field `name` is contained in all tables. How do I specify the required? I tried this:

```
->where('table3.name', 'hello')->get();
```

but I get an error - Field not found

Comment: `table3` is relation not table name right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`with` method related with relative method created in `Model`, it is not table name. you must be use table name in place of `table_name_for_table3.name`. But you can use `whereHas` method

```
$search_string = "hello";
$models = Model::with('table1', 'table2', 'table3', 'table4', 'table5')
->whereHas('table3',function($t)use($search_string){
   $t->where('name',$search_string);
})
->where('name', 'hello')->get();
```

[From Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations)

> These methods allow you to add customized constraints to a
>   relationship constraint, such as checking the content of a comment:

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$models = Model::with('table1 AS t1', 'table2 AS t2', 'table3 AS t3', 'table4 AS t4', 'table5 AS t5')
->where('t1.name', 'hello')->get();
```

Comment: Call to undefined relationship [table1 AS sm] on model [App\\ n_Models]

Comment: Alias can be made by `whereHas` method as `whereHas(tablea as t1,function({$t}))`